# Box2D Cocos2d JS

Tags: cocos2d-js, box2dweb, convex-polygon

[image]I want to create a slope like in attached image in Box2D Cocos2d JS.
However, I am unable to create it properly when attached sprites to it.
My code is:

```
new b2Vec2(0, 0),
new b2Vec2(100 / worldScale, -50 / worldScale),
new b2Vec2(200 / worldScale, 0 / worldScale)
```

The image dimensions is 200 * 50, and worldScale = 30.

Comment: Hi, what version of Cocos2D-JS are you using?

Comment: Hi, i am using 3.7 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I see you're using negative coordinates (-50). Everything in Cocos2d-JS (the default viewport) is positive ({0,0} is bottom left point).

To debug slope positioning I suggest you to use Box2d **DebugDraw** first, to see the actual slope you've described and then to place your sprite based on those wireframes.
Cocos2d-JS will clear it's own canvas in the update function, so you'll need to put another debug canvas on top of it, for DebugDraw.

[This example helped me to add debug draw to my box2d sandbox successfully](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-js/issues/885)

> add this code to update function

```
var debugDraw = new Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw();
debugDraw.SetSprite(document.getElementById("test").getContext("2d"));
// test is the id of another canvas which debugdraw works on
debugDraw.SetDrawScale(30.0); 
debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.3);
debugDraw.SetLineThickness(1.0);
debugDraw.SetFlags(Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit |
Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw.e_jointBit);
this.world.SetDebugDraw(debugDraw); this.world.DrawDebugData();
```

> box2d use a different coordinate frame than cocos, so you need to do
>    transform 180 degrees. add this to the style of debug canvas
>
> `-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg)`; //and some other browsers' style